# Get Gurobi IIS using Pyomo and gurobipy

Tags: gurobi, pyomo

Could someone walk me through the steps to get the IIS from a Pyomo model using gurobipy?

`opt = SolverFactory('gurobi',solver_io='python')`

As a reference, this is what I use in JuMP

```
function getIIS(m::JuMP.Model)
  grb_model = m.internalModel.inner
  num_constrs = Gurobi.num_constrs(grb_model)
  Gurobi.computeIIS(grb_model)
  iis_constrs = Gurobi.get_intattrarray(grb_model, "IISConstr",  1, num_constrs)
  m.linconstr[find(iis_constrs)]
end
```

So, basically I need access to the internal gurobi model to run the `computeIIS` function, and then I need a way to map the array of rows to the actual Pyomo constraints.

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can pass this as an option to Gurobi when you call 
the solve function by using options_string. Then, Gurobi's Model.write() function will write the file. In this case, you would write a .ilp file, but other file formats exist for different purposes. An example:

```
solver_parameters = "ResultFile=model.ilp" # write an ILP file to print the IIS
```

Then, you would add options_string when you call the solve function:

```
results = solver.solve(instance, options_string=solver_parameters)
```

You can also string multiple options together with the following syntax. Note the leading empty space within the quotes for the LogToConsole and ResultFile options:

```
 solver_parameters = "TimeLimit=60" # set time limit (seconds)
            solver_parameters += " LogToConsole=0" # 0 =  turn off console output
            solver_parameters += " ResultFile=model.ilp" # write a MIP start file to warm start
```

The documentation found here applies to solving a model with Gurobi, and the examples at the bottom work with any Gurobi file format:
http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/refman/solving_a_model2.html

Finally, this link explains the different file formats that Gurobi can write: http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/refman/model_file_formats.html#sec:FileFormats

Answer (score 0):

See this Pyomo example using suffixes. I believe it's doing what you want.

https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/examples/pyomo/suffixes/gurobi_ampl_iis.py

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I was expecting. This uses the AMPL interface and I want to use gurobipy directly. I want access to the Gurobi model to execute functions from the Gurobi python API.